# How to split a string into html tags using python regex?

Tags: python, regex

Say I have a string:

```
"<blockquote>Quote</blockquote><br />text <h3>This is a title</h3>"
```

Expected Output:

`["<blockquote>Quote</blockquote><br />", "text", "<h3>This is a title</h3>"]`

I need both the opening and closing tags to be included in the same item, as above.

I've tried:
`re.split("<*>*</*>", s)`

I'm quite new with Regex so any help is appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: "Every time you attempt to parse HTML with regular expressions, the unholy child weeps the blood of virgins, and Russian hackers pwn your webapp. Parsing HTML with regex summons tainted souls into the realm of the living. HTML and regex go together like love, marriage, and ritual infanticide. "

Comment: "Even Jon Skeet cannot parse HTML using regular expressions."

Comment: A proper HTML/XML/DOM parser.

Comment: A more explanatory article on "why not use Regex": https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/  Most importantly: **Parsing HTML is a solved problem. You do not need to solve it. You just need to be lazy** (and use another library)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` to do this.

```
import re
s = "<blockquote>Quote</blockquote><br />text <h3>This is a title</h3>"
re.findall(r'<[^>]*>.*?</[^>]*>(?:<[^>]*/>)?|[^<>]+', s)
# ['<blockquote>Quote</blockquote><br />', 'text ', '<h3>This is a title</h3>']
```

But avoid parsing html data like directly using regex and consider using something like `BeautifulSoup`

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
>>> soup.findAll()
[<blockquote>Quote</blockquote>, <br/>, <h3>This is a title</h3>]
>>> soup.findAll()[0].text
'Quote'
>>> [s for s in soup.strings]
['Quote', 'text ', 'This is a title']
```

Comment: Could you direct me to a Beautiful Soup solution?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Works. Thank you!